Trying to use DocFX results in error "No instances of MSBuild could be detected"
I've created a docFx project using the commandline wizard. When I try to render the documentation with docfx ./docfx.json I get the following error:
ExtractMetadataException: No instances of MSBuild could be detected.
Try calling RegisterInstance or RegisterMSBuildPath to manually register one.
     InvalidOperationException: No instances of MSBuild could be detected.
     Try calling RegisterInstance or RegisterMSBuildPath to manually register one.
       at VisualStudioInstance RegisterDefaults()
       at void EnsureMSBuildLocator() in DotnetApiCatalog.cs:126
  at void EnsureMSBuildLocator() in DotnetApiCatalog.cs:134
  at async Task Exec(MetadataJsonConfig config, DotnetApiOptions options, string configDirectory, string outputDirectory) in DotnetApiCatalog.cs:60
  at void <Execute>b__0() in DefaultCommand.cs:45
  at int Run(LogOptions options, Action run) in CommandHelper.cs:48
  at int Execute(CommandContext context, Options options) in DefaultCommand.cs:31
  at Task<int> Execute(CommandContext context, CommandSettings settings) in CommandOfT.cs:40
  at async Task<int> Execute(CommandTree leaf, CommandTree tree, CommandContext context, ITypeResolver resolver, IConfiguration configuration) in CommandExecutor.cs:166

This is the output of dotnet --list-sdks:
7.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

The target project uses .NET 7.0, and it compiles (it's a newly created project, empty save for the default "Hello world!" print)
This is the docfx.json file:
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "src": "C:/Users/my_user/Repos/Tests/docfx_test/dotnet_project/dotnet_project",
          "files": [
            "**/*.csproj"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": ""
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.{md,yml}"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "output": "_site",
    "template": [
      "default",
      "modern"
    ],
    "globalMetadata": {
      "_appName": "TestDocumentation",
      "_appTitle": "TestDocumentation",
      "_enableSearch": true,
      "pdf": true
    }
  }
}


Do you have Visual Studio 2022 installed? It's a prerequisite

Yes. I'm actually running the command from VS 22's powershell.

Is the behavior different if you run the command in the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022"?

No, I get the same thing

From the stack trace, it appears that the docfx tool is using the Microsoft.Build.Locator API. (MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance() is part of that API.) In the Visual Studio Installer under "Individual Components", search for "MSBuild" and verify that it is installed. (Also in the PowerShell and Cmd shells for VS 2022 you should be able to run msbuild --version.) If MSBuild is installed and docfx can't locate it, check the github repo for docfx. See if there is an issue and possibly file an issue.

msbuild --version returns: 17.7.2.37605, so it looks like it's installed... I'll try the github, thanks.

It works now, but I'm not sure why. I tried uninstalling all .NET runtimes except 6.0, it didn't work. I then reinstalled version 7.0, it still didn't work. I installed 8.0, didn't work.
After that I uninstalled and reinstalled docfx itself and now it works. I'm not sure which combination of reinstalls did the trick, but clearly something had not been properly initialized when I first installed docfx.

reinstalling also fixed this error on my machine.  https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/ says docfx requires .NET SDK 8.0 or higher, just for reference.
